# Аналог инструкции BSWAP для SSE

Tags: ассемблер, sse

Как проще всего сделать побайтовую перестановку в регистре XMM аналогичную BSWAP?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56407741/reverse-byte-order-in-xmm-or-ymm-register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ни в одном из сетов SIMD инструкций нет прямого аналога BSWAP, есть более сложная команда [PSHUFB](https://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/simdimg/si.php?f=pshufb), но она переставляет байты в произвольном порядке в соответствии с маской.

[Полный перечень SIMD команд](https://www.officedaytime.com/simd512e/)